# Can I just delete leases in DHCP to force a new lease on client?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

I need to force a DHCP renewal on all my clients (to make them point to my new DNS server).

Some of them have about 4 days left in their leases.  Can I just delete the leases from the server? Will this force them to check in to DHCP again and grab another lease or is this a bad idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a bad idea. They won't try and renew the lease until it is expiring. Deleting the lease will cause other machines to be able to get that IP. What you want is either to run ipconfig /renew via [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) or to script the renew in PowerShell and run it remotely.

Alternatively, if the users reboot they should get the new configuration options.

Comment: Ahh thats very useful info.  Thank you!  I'll push a script out that renews dhcp. Thanks!!

Comment: Unless you have a really huge park of machines, you might also want to reduce the lease time to a few hours in case you need to do that again in the future.